# gGet the position from the LocationService angular2

Tags: geolocation, angular2-services

I have a location service

```
export class MapService {
  location: Position;
   allOptions;

  ngOnInit() {
          if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
              position => {
                this.location = position;
              }
            );
         }}}
```

In my component.ts method, i have

```
let pos;
constructor(private locationService: MapService) { 
    this.pos = locationService.location;
   }

print(){
console.log(this.pos);
}
```

when i test it i have pos is *undefined*:

How can get the position(lat, lng) from the LocationService ??

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written a service is incorrect, you can read more about services [here](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#services).

Check below for the solution,

```
@Injectable()
export class MapService {
  location: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  
  constructor(){
     if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
         position => {
              this.location.next(position);
          }  
        )
     }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private ms : MapService){
    this.ms.location.subscribe(pos =>  {
      console.log(pos);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OR4vRHk1DGBVqM1mQmEN?p=preview)!!